# youtube iframe api not working in firefox with backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, youtube-api

So i'm trying to implement youtube API in backbone code.

I put the API in a view and try to run everything from there

It works great in chrome but isen't running in firefox, the event that's suppose to trigger when the youtube API is done loading isen't fired. If even tried putting alert in there to see if it was context related, this alert would run in chrome but not in firefox.

Anyone seen anything like this before?

I'm using backbone 0.9 and the youtube iframe api

live example: http://alpha.mychannls.com/channel/8

relevant code

```
App.Views.youtubePlayer = Backbone.View.extend({
defaults: {
    'wmode': 'transparent',
    'height': '420',
    'width': '740',
    'volume': '40',
    'playerVars': {
        'wmode': 'transparent',
        'origin': 'http://www.youtube.com',
        'enablejsapi': 1,
        'autoplay': 0,
        'controls': 1,
        'iv_load_policy': 3,
        'showinfo': 0,
        'rel': 0,
        'allowfullscreen': 1,
        'allowtransparency': 'yes'
    }
},

initialize: function(options) {
    //bind youtubeplay event to play method
    this.collection.bind('youtubePlay', this.play, this);
    //bind youtubestop to stop method
    this.collection.bind('youtubeStop', this.stop, this);
    //extend this.o so the options are globally accessable
    this.o = $.extend(true, this.defaults, options);
    this.render();
},

render: function() {
    //create a new youtube player
    var view = this;
    console.log("this is run by firefox");
    this.ytplayer = new window.YT.Player('ytplayer', {
        'events': {
            'onReady': view.onPlayerReady,
            'onError': view.onError,
            'onStateChange': view.onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
    return this;
},
//when youtube player is ready to run
onPlayerReady: function(e){
    console.log('this function isent run in firefox');
    //start the first video
    App.videos.youtubeready();

}

});
```

outside the backbone code because youtube api player needs to be declared global

```
var tag = document.createElement('script'); 
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    App.youtubeplayer = new App.Views.youtubePlayer( { el: '#ytplayer' , collection :     App.videos }  );
}
```

entire code can be found here

http://alpha.mychannls.com/js/channel.js

Comment: It would really help to see a live demo of your full page, not just the standalone JavaScript. That way we could use the Firefox JavaScript debugger to step through the code and see what's going on.

Comment: Jeff: I'm seeing a very similar problem, related to FF + Backbone.js and the YT IFrame API. Each time the user clicks to navigate the application (pushState), the YT IFrame re-triggers the onReady event. It may be possible that Firefox is triggering the YT Iframe to reload onPopState(), but it is hard to tell -- the behavior at least is indicating that.

I'll try to create a better reduced test case for this.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the answer to the problem. I implemented this and it actually works great now.  Here's the gist of it:

Firefox has 2 separate implementations of an IFrame. The first implementation is before the onload event is triggered by the browser. The second is after the onload event. What this means for Backbone/Angular or other event driven javascript application frameworks that operate after the onload event is the Youtube IFrame API implementation of adding the IFrame dynamically to your page will not work.

The solution I found was also located on in the YT IFrame API documentation, but you wouldn't know it.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player

See the section after the JS, about creating the IFrame tag yourself? It is exactly right! So all you need to do is have the IFrame in your page when the page is sent from the server (ie: your index.html) or whichever main file you're using.

In your case, it looks like you've got a Backbone/Marionette app, so this solution should work fine for you.

```
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="1" height="1" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com" 
frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Something like the above code placed inside your main document and referenced from the Backbone app will work.

Good luck, just respond back if you need more help.

Jeff: FWIW - this IFrame/Firefox problem has existed since at least 2005 (the date of the obscure post I found). You might want to note it in the IFrame documentation for dynamic single page Javascript application developers, as this isn't easy to debug.